# Returning Octave values to Scilab

Tags: c++, octave, scilab

I'm writing c++ code that returns Octave function output to Scilab environment.

The relevant code is given below-

```
//Pass values from Scilab to Octave
sciErr= getMatrixOfDouble(pvApiCtx, piAddr, &iRows, &iCols, &pdblReal);    
Matrix matrix_double = Matrix (iRows,iCols);
for (r=0;r<iRows;r++)
{
 for(c=0;c<iCols;c++)
 {
   matrix_double(r,c)=(pdblReal[r]+c);                        
 }
}
in(i-2)=octave_value (matrix_double);

octave_value_list out = feval (pstData[0], in, 1);//Call Octave function 

dim_vector d = (out(0).matrix_value().dims()); //Get dimensions of Octave output

//Return Octave output to Scilab
if(out(0).is_double_type())
{
  poutput = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * d(0) * d(1));
  for(int l = 0 ; l < d(0) ; l++)
  {
    for(int m = 0 ; m < d(1) ; m++)
    {
      poutput[l+d(0)*m]=(out(0).matrix_value ()(l,m));
    }
  }
}
sciErr=createMatrixOfDouble(pvApiCtx, nbInputArgument(pvApiCtx) + 1, d(0), d(1),poutput);
free(poutput);
AssignOutputVariable(pvApiCtx, 1) = nbInputArgument(pvApiCtx) + 1;
ReturnArguments(pvApiCtx);
```

On Scilab console, the input is

```
-->a=[1 24 92; 59 28 211]
a  =

1.     24.    92.   
59.    28.    211. 


-->b=call_octave("transpose",a)
b  =

1.    59.  
2.    60.  
3.    61.
```

For any Octave function, the first row of the output is correct. The  subsequent rows have 1 added to the previous row. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Probably not real good advice [printf debugging](http://www.oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/DebugCPP/Volume/techniques.html), but you could add a `sciprint("Val [%d,%d]: %f\n", l,m, poutput[l+d(0)*m]);` to your for-loop to check if the matrix-values are retrieved correctly.

Comment: Could you also provide the code which writes the data to Octave?

Comment: The code has been edited.